# Why does a Behat PHP command work in terminal, but not in Jenkins?

Tags: php, linux, jenkins, terminal, behat

I am working on figuring out how to get Jenkins to run Behat tests for us automatically. So I installed Jenkins on my local machine (running on Ubuntu 12.10). I have been able to run Behat for several weeks now from my local machine.

In my command line I switch to the directory and run the following command:

```
cd /virtualhosts/automated-testing/behat/ecash
php bin/behat -p phantomjs features/populate.feature
```

From here it spits out all the pretty syntax about which steps are running and how each do. That works great. Then I drop the following into Jenkins:

```
whoami
cd /virtualhosts/automated-testing/behat/ecash
pwd
php bin/behat -p phantomjs features/populate.feature
```

The "whoami" returns "jenkins", no surprise there. The "pwd" shows the directory I specified in the previous step. Then when it gets to the PHP command it gives me this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Behat\Mink\Driver\DriverInterface' not found in /virtualhosts/automated-testing/behat/ecash/vendor/behat/mink-browserkit-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/BrowserKitDriver.php on line 34
```

It then goes into a stack trace. So this has left me scratching my head. I thought maybe it is using a different php.ini file. So I ran "php -i" from Jenkins and my terminal and got the same file. Then I thought that maybe it didn't like the user. So I added the Jenkins user to my group (since I created the files). Still doesn't work.

Soooo, what am I doing wrong here? Why the heck does this not work? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How have you installed the Behat/Mink and Behat/MinkBrowserKit packages...both via composer? Do you now have another project directory for the Jenkins user and are both packages installed in the vendors folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is a bit of a permissions issue. Jenkins is running as user "jenkins" (obviously). But the files are owned by me. So if I chown the entire project as "jenkins" being the owner I can now get Jenkins to run it. Of course now I can't run it as myself.

But that isn't too big a deal. I just checkout the files from my repository as the Jenkins user using "sudo -u" and our QA Jenkins install can run Behat all day long.

Thanks!